# Doubt in PMDC motor pulsed switching current

Tags: mosfet, pwm, dc-motor, power-electronics, motor-controller

I am controlling a dc motor by switching through the MOSFET. I am able to run the DC MOTOR and I have measured the current through scope by putting a RESISTOR SERIES of the DC MOTOR.

My doubt is, since the motor is an inductive load I was expecting the DC current will be averaged by switching at High frequency(switching frequency 20KHZ), but what I get is a pulsed current which matches with the input PWM.

Why I don’t get an average current?

Why I get that spike?

Control details:

PMDC motor

Motor input Voltage:180VDC

Mosfet:IRFP460

Freewheeling Diode:MUR3060

Switching speed:20KHZ

PWM control.

Series Resistor (for measuring current) Value:0.5E/20W ceramic resistor.

[image: Scope Image]

Circuit:
[image]

Comment: schematic please

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem...

The current which I am measuring is a Mosfet ON-Current, once the mosfet is OFF the current will be "free-Wheeled"..I should measure the current in the freewheeling path where i will get both ON-CURRENT & OFF-CURRENT.Which will be a average current as expected..

for testing I have placed the resistor at freewheeling path at 180V+, and the current which I measured is the average current.

Current scope image..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to have oscilloscope measurement errors if you are trying to infer the current through R1. Firstly, your scope is grounded and, aparently, so is the source of your mosfet so, maybe you are using differential scope measurements? Not so according to your scope picture. So maybe you have isolated the scope ground from the circuit ground and are connecting your *now-isolated* scope ground to the drain of the mosfet.

This will be a nasty way of trying to view the voltage across R1 and the excess capacitance load on the mosfet will give all sorts of strange anomalies.

A better solution is to put R1 in the source wire of your mosfet - I'd use a much smaller value too - maybe 0.1 ohms. Now you can connect your grounded scope across R1 and see the motor current in more detail.

Or maybe you are using the LTS 15NP - I have my doubts about this given the data sheet I've read.